# Why would the documentation say to wire a pole of the 3-way occupancy switch to ground?

Tags: electrical, switch, grounding

I'm currently wiring up an occupancy sensor to a 3-way switch, I'm leaving one of the mechanical switches in place, and here is the [wiring instructions](http://www.legrand.us/~/media/products/resources/pass-and-seymour/Instruction%20Sheets/341002_rev3.ashx).

according to the instructions I need to wire one of the poles on the second switch to ground (fig 5). I've never seen this before, is it safe to do? Do I wire that pole and the ground nut together to go to ground?

> [image: Multilocation configuration]

Comment: That does seem odd, I wonder why they didn't suggest wiring it to Neutral, which should be identical to ground to the device. Interestingly, on their product page they say _[No neutral required](https://www.legrand.us/passandseymour/motion-sensors/occupancy/single-pole-2-wire-multiple-loads/rw600utc.aspx)_, so maybe this is their way of getting around requiring a neutral and maybe the current passed to the ground is low enough to not be an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Follow the manufacturer's instructions for wiring the device.** If the instructions say make a ground connection, then make it.

For argument's sake, that ground could very well be for nothing more than grounding the switch (so it wouldn't necessarily be a *pole*).

However, it is likely that this device is indeed passing some current to ground. Below is a reference from a competing manufacturer of similar products. Notice that this only becomes a concern when combined with many such (*twenty!*) devices, or with other devices that are prone to leaking current to ground. Also note that **this is only a concern on GFCI protected circuits**.

[image]